# Moving "if" statement condition to a local variable makes C# compiler unhappy

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Could you please explain me the reason of the following situation.

Today I wrote the code (only variables names are changed):

```
private void Foo() 
{
    int firstInteger, secondInteger;
    const string firstStringValue = "1", secondStringValue = "2";

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstStringValue) && int.TryParse(firstStringValue, out firstInteger) &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secondStringValue) && int.TryParse(secondStringValue, out secondInteger))
    {
        // Using firstInteger and secondInteger here
        firstInteger++;
        secondInteger++;
    }
}
```

Everything was fine until I decided to move the ***if*** condition to a variable:

```
private void Foo()
{
    int firstInteger, secondInteger;
    const string firstStringValue = "1", secondStringValue = "2";

    bool firstIntegerAndSecondIntegerAreSpecified = 
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstStringValue) && int.TryParse(firstStringValue, out firstInteger) &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secondStringValue) && int.TryParse(secondStringValue, out secondInteger);

    if (firstIntegerAndSecondIntegerAreSpecified)
    {
        // Use firstInteger and secondInteger here
        firstInteger++;
        secondInteger++;
    }
}
```

Now the compiler underlines *firstInteger* and *secondInteger* variables with error "Local variable might not be initialized before accessing".

But why? The only thing I made is refactored the code a bit. And as I see it the logic is the same.

Comment: Why are you checking for NullOrWhitespace? int.TryParse takes care of it for you (i.e. whitespace results in a false return value), thereby making your code so much more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, **spender**. You're right, better to use int.TryParse() here only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler (or rather, the specification) doesn't spot the relationship between the value of `firstIntegerAndSecondIntegerAreSpecified` and the calls to `int.TryParse`. In the first form, it could work out that execution would only enter the body if both calls to `int.TryParse` had executed, and therefore both had definitely assigned values (due to the `out` parameters). Therefore there was no problem in the `if` block.

The rules for definite assignment don't cover the idea that `firstIntegerAndSecondIntegerAreSpecified` will only be true if both calls have been made, therefore in the body of the `if` block, the variables still aren't definitely assigned, hence the error.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler is not built to be clever enough to figure out that a true value in the boolean variable ensures that the values in the integer are set. The compiler only tracks execution paths, not varaible values.

In the first case the compiler knows that it's impossible to enter the if statement without the `TryParse` calls setting the variables. In the second case the if statement is detached from the `TryParse` calls, so the compiler would have to track the variable value to figure out the relation.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, the compiler can look at the `if` condition and *know* that the body can't execute unless both of the variables have values (`TryParse` *always* sets its `out` parameter, even when it fails).

When you refactor that condition out to a variable, the compiler would have to trace that local variable to make sure that it can't be written to from when it's assigned to when it's used as the condition. Since the compiler isn't that clever, it can't be sure that your variables are initialized ("definitely assigned"), so it gives you an error.

Comment: Yes, now I get it. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement can only be entered if both of the expressions are executed, but the `bool` can be assigned prematurely because of short-circuiting - if the first string fails to parse, the compiler skips parsing the second string, because regardless of the result, the bool's value must be false.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler gives this error sometimes. Of course if you follow the logic of your code, you'll see that the variables are always initialized before use. But the compiler doesn't run the logic, it only acts according to some basic rules. And this is why it often gives this error even if in fact there is no error in the logic.

The solution is simple: just initialize all variables when you declare them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jon's answer -

It could be easier to handle both integers separately. And there is no need to check for `NullOrWhiteSpace` either.

```
int.TryParse(firstStringValue, out firstInteger)
    firstInteger++;

int.TryParse(secondStringValue, out secondInteger)
    secondInteger++;
```

You could even Extract this piece in a separate method

Comment: I think, there would be some 'logical' demand because of which questioner is incrementing both the integers together, when  both the IFs returns true after parsing integer value. If this is the case, your suggestion would break the logic. Otherwise, it's definitely OK. Anyway, there is no need of NullOrWhiteSpace - you are right!